# Merge streams in java

Tags: java, stream

I'm creating a Java JWS application. That application is logging some useful (for me) debug stuff to the system.out. Now, application will be used by 3rd party and i don't want them to see debug log.
My idea is following: application should write all the status messages to the custom stream. If logged user is "dev", then custom stream should be "merged" with system.out and console should print all new and prior (already existing) data from my custom stream. If logged user is somebody other than "dev", all status messages will remained logged into the custom stream and won't be visible in the console.

How could i achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache's [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or [commons logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) with cutom filters. There's a [Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) that comes with the JDK. You can also create a custom logger considering the types of users. You can direct the logs in proper output destination depending on the user type. All logs should be stored somewhere regardless of user type to monitor though.

Comment: Anything other then using external jars?

Comment: @guest86 You can use the one that comes with the JDK - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html

Comment: Ok, but can i store the log into the memory by default and just start printing it on the system.out if needed? Will that consume too much memory if i have large log?

Comment: @guest86 It obviously depends on your application. Question is - in a given time, how much maximum logs do you exepect in your app? If it is reasonable, then yes create a simple logger class and store it and print it later even though I think it's easier and safer to flush it than wasting memory by storing. What if your app crashes and you didn't log anything? So make sure to print the logs when an incident like that happens.